# What is the natural usage of "quelle horreur" in English? (Is it different from the French?)

Tags: foreign-phrases

I have a vague recollection that if I read an English-language piece that contained "Quelle horreur!" it would imply a sarcastic feigning of disgust for something trivial, likely to be used in a literary, highbrow context. For example, imagine some Vanity Fair or Esquire piece about Internet delays with an anecdote "My son tells me that because of Amazon S3 delays, he now has to wait 30 minutes after his final exams are done to access his grade. *Quelle horreur!*"

Is this the primary meaning when used in English? Is that different from its normal meaning in French? ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_French_expressions_in_English) says "can be used sarcastically", but not that this would be the dominant meaning)

Comment: My question is just about how to use this phrase correctly in an English context without implying something that I do not mean.

Comment: Yes, I'd say it's encountered most often when an onlooker decides that someone is making a montagne out of a taupinière.

Comment: Quelle horreur! means **How awful or horrible!** in English. In French, it is not at all highbrow and the expression is not "used" in English. As with much French used in English, the reader or interlocutor is expected to understand the original. Using French in English like that implies what the French call "une certaine complicité" between the speaker and listener/reader. Qu'à Dieu ne plaise. Give 'em that one.

Comment: I'd agree with the ironic use, like "Big deal!" or *Pretentious? Moi?*

Comment: It's only high brow in the sense that you need the right education to get it or find out where to decipher it....

Comment: I use it myself as a wryly humorous reaction to, for example, a difficult page of music or a sudden rainstorm.

Comment: Oh, what a question! **How Frightful!**

Comment: It's the sort of thing that children studying French might say to each other as a humorous remark. Certainly when I was at school they taught about using "Quel(le)" with a noun to express surprise or delight, and if you're a bored kid that's one of the more entertaining parts of French class. It's evidently enjoyed by enough people to escape the classroom, at least somewhat. But that means it's used with some humour or irony, it's not like "et cetera" which is used as if it was English without thinking it's foreign.

Comment: Outside of literary usage, English usage of this term is commonly meant sarcastically or humorously. That's the simple cultural reality here. The term is *used* in English - that is why we are having this discussion in the first place.

Comment: @KateBunting - I've heard "Lions and tigers and bears oh my" used in that way, by an elementary school administrator (emailing a colleague) to mean that a parent was making too big a deal out of something. My guess is that "quelle horreur" could be used in English with or without sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Rest assured that if you are speaking in English, and someone inserts the French *quelle horreur*, they are being sarcastic, dramatic. It’s bad, but not *that* bad.

iWeb (The 14 Billion Word Web Corpus) offers some usage examples:

> *A while ago parking meters showed up in front. Quelle horreur! Ok, so it costs me 25 cents more now, to go get my brew stuff.*
>
> *No bathroom breaks, no food and, quelle horreur, no champagne to ring in the New Year. Houston, we have a problem!*
>
> *Caroline Sieber and [Steel’s daughter] Vanessa Traina showed up in the same dress and the same shoes . . . *Quelle horreur!**
>
> [And so on . .
> .](https://www.english-corpora.org/iweb/?c=iweb&q=103715772)